# python more fonts in glut (glutBitmapCharacter)

Tags: python, opengl, text, fonts, pyopengl

I'm using glutBitmapCharacter of pyOpenGL in Python, but the only fonts I can choose to use are helvetica and times_new_roman. Is it possible to add more fonts?

Answer (score 0):

Not without modifying your GLUT implementation to add additional `enum`s and font bitmaps.

Comment: How can I do that? In OpenGL.GLUT.fonts I see a list of GLUT_... fonts, but when I try to add one I get an error (of course).